# Несколько правил в htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, apache-modules

Есть самописный сайт, в котором все урлы обрабатывается файлом index.php

Требуется добавить к этому сайту scss с обработкой на php(?!?!?!)

Установил scssphp от leafo. По их мануалам вся обработка файлов scss идет через php-файл style.php. Т.е. идет запрос scss-файла типа

```
<link rel="stylesheets" href="/stylesheets.php/mystyle.scss">
```

.htaccess

```
AddDefaultCharset utf-8
php_flag display_errors on
php_value error_reporting -1

RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteBase /

/* Здесь должна быть обработка scss-файлов? */
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ^style\.php\/([a-z0-9\.\/]*\.scss)$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*).scss stylesheets.php/$1 [NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [NC]
```

Помогите написать правило для htaccess, чтобы все файлы формата scss переправлялись на файл stylesheets.php

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteRule ^(.*).scss$ stylesheets.php?file=%{REQUEST_URI} [QSA,L]
```

В `$_GET['file']` будет путь к запрашиваемому файлу, например, `/assets/css/style.scss`